# Producer and Consumer Conception in Web Services

Tags: api, rest, web-services

I'm new to web services and just bumped into the conceptions of producer(server) and consumer(client). As I can search from other sources, the producer is defined as the app that produces data, while the consumer is the app that consumes these data. They are typically connected by a queue service (like AWS SQS). This is understandable when you take an online ordering service as the producer, and it sends ordering data to the backend shipping service, which in this case is a consumer. But it starts to confuse me when in banking scenarios when users query their account statement on their mobile app, and the backend database returns the data to users. In this case, is the frontend mobile app a producer or a consumer? If you say it's a producer, the actual outcome is the mobile app receiving data from the backend; if you say it's a consumer, it's actually sending account statement requests to the backend, just like an online ordering service sending ordering requests to shipping service.

Answer (score 0):

In my view,producer is the one that provides Web API and consumer is the one that invoke the Web API to finish paticular tasks. FYI.